# Parse Shopify Json response in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, shopify-api

I know this is a variation on a common theme, but I need to parse a Json response from Shopify, to extract id and price, which is coming in the following literal format:

```
{"data":{
    "variant0":{
        "productVariant":{
            "id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/44012325711321",
            "price":"31.58"}},
    "variant1":{
        "productVariant":null},
    "variant2":{
        "productVariant":{
            "id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/31271232862321",
            "price":"133.98"}}
        },
"extensions":{
    "cost":{
        "requestedQueryCost":30,
        "actualQueryCost":30,
        "throttleStatus":{
            "maximumAvailable":1000.0,
            "currentlyAvailable":970,
            "restoreRate":50.0}}}}
```

The total count of variant[n] is not known, and they are not returned as a JsonArray. Occasionally the response (eg variant1) is null.

I have the following basic code, but the null value of variant1 means the loop ends early. How do I check for the existence of variant[n], and/or how to parse this Json better to extract values?

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button20Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      jSonValue: TJSonValue;
      i        : integer;
      resp     : string;
      id, price: string;
      function GETVALUES(): boolean;
        begin
          try
            id     := jSonValue.GetValue<string>('data.variant' + i.tostring + '.productVariant.id');
            price  := jSonValue.GetValue<string>('data.variant' + i.tostring + '.productVariant.price');
            result := True;
          except
            on e: exception do
              result := false;
          end;
        end;

    begin
      resp      := mmInputs.Lines.Text;
      jSonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(resp);
      i         := 0;
      while GETVALUES() do
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.add('variant' + i.tostring + ' id=' + id + '=' + price);
          inc(i);
        end;
      Memo1.Lines.add('pointsRemaining:' + jSonValue.GetValue<string>('extensions.cost.throttleStatus.currentlyAvailable'));
      jSonValue.free;
    end;
```

Comment: Check out TJSONValue.TryGetValue (https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue.TryGetValue) that might help you. At least you will know if valid JSON has been returned.

Comment: I think the JSON is valid - the null response indicates that the variant was not found, ie the input had erroneous id. That's correct and I need to handle this response. I just don't know how to check for the existence of 'data.variant1' (to see if node exists). I'm only checking for data.varaiant1.productVariant.id which throws error

Answer (score 0):

```
  procedure TfrmMain.Button22Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jSonValue: TJSonValue;
  i        : integer;
  id, price: string;

  function GETVALUES: boolean;
    begin
      try
        id     := jSonValue.GetValue<string>('data.variant' + i.tostring + '.productVariant.id');
        price  := jSonValue.GetValue<string>('data.variant' + i.tostring + '.productVariant.price');
        result := True;
      except
        on e: exception do
          result := false;
      end;
    end;
    
  function VariantObjExists: boolean;
    var
      v: string;
    begin
      result := jSonValue.TryGetValue<string>('data.variant' + i.tostring + '.productVariant', v);
      if result then
        Memo1.Lines.add('variant' + i.tostring + ' = null');
    end;

var
  MoreResults: boolean;
  resp       : string;
begin
  resp        := mmInputs.Lines.Text;
  jSonValue   := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(resp);
  i           := 0;
  MoreResults := True;
  repeat
    if GETVALUES then
      Memo1.Lines.add('variant' + i.tostring + ' id=' + id + '=' + price)
    else
      MoreResults := VariantObjExists;

    inc(i);
  until not MoreResults;

  Memo1.Lines.add('pointsRemaining:' + jSonValue.GetValue<string>('extensions.cost.throttleStatus.currentlyAvailable'));
  jSonValue.free;
end;
```